# Can't figure out why one team site has checkout the other not

Tags: team-sites, homepage

I have two team sites on the same SP2013 on-premise farm, I'm in full control on both team sites (not the farm, though).
They both have different ribbons on the home page and I can't figure out why.
I have checked:

- Identical Site Features (except Workflow)
- Identical Site Pages -> Settings (including Versioning settings)
- Identical Site Types (STS#0 - Team Site)
- Identical Home Page Types (Wiki, default home pages)

The first difference is on the ribbons:

[image: screenshot of different ribbons]

The only difference I understand is the Workflow missing because that's the only Feature not enabled on the second site. But why is there an Approval group on the first and a Check Out button on the second ? Why is there a Title Bar Properties on the first and a Page Library group on the second ?

The second difference is in what came up as the default Home Pages and how they look in Edit Mode, although they have the same Page Layout. The first one has Header, Body, Right Column box titles and "Add a Web Part" buttons. The second doesn't have any of that although I can add web parts through the ribbon. Why ?

First site:
[image: screenshot of first site Page Edit]

Second site:
[image: screenshot of second site Page Edit]

Thanks for your help, I'm not enough familiar with SP2013 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the site pages library settings (or other library where you store the home page) I don't have time to test but probably on one you enabled require content approval in the library settings and in the other one you have enable check-in and out. You wrote the site features are the same, but are the site collection features the same (they are have separate pages in the site settings, you might have some differences around the publishing infrastructure and features)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I did not use site collections, actually I do not even have "Site Collections" as an option anywhere. The two team sites are actually both subsites on the root of the container (https://teamsites.x/sitea and https://teamsites.x/siteb. That's pretty clear in Sharepoint Designer. (sorry I figure out how to do line breaks in this editor...)

Comment: ok then just check the site pages settings. probably difference is there.

Comment: silly 5 minutes comment edition policy :-/ I was about to add this:<br/>So going to Site Contents -> Site Pages [...] -> Settings I have on both sites:<br/>- content approval: No<br/>- Create major versions<br/>- require checkout: No<br/>and exactly the same settings on the root site as well. (wtf is wrong with formatting comments on this site?)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. It relies on how the Home.aspx home page was created. I don't know if there is a different template or something but:

- The default Home.aspx that comes up upon creation of a subsite has the characteristics of my second site screenshots above.
- Creating a new Site Page from Sharepoint Designer using the button "Add Web Part Page" creates an empty page with the characteristics of my first site above.

Took me a few hours unsuccessful research before I simply tried that :-)